# Aggregating combination sequences

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, sequence

I have sample dataset that I would like to aggregate by `user_id`.  Each record represents a sign-up.

```
> test
   user_id                time    plan
1        1 2017-06-23 20:00:00 monthly
2        2 2017-07-20 20:00:00 monthly
3        3 2017-06-03 20:00:00 monthly
4        1 2017-07-03 20:00:00 monthly
5        2 2017-05-11 20:00:00  yearly
6        3 2017-07-27 20:00:00  yearly
7        1 2017-05-09 20:00:00  yearly
8        2 2017-01-15 19:00:00  yearly
9        3 2017-08-18 20:00:00  yearly
10       1 2017-01-30 19:00:00 monthly
```

Each user has signed up for different plans in a different order(`time`). 
For example, the sequence of user 1 is `monthly-yearly-monthly- monthly`, therefore user 1 has switched **two** times.

User 2 has `yearly-yearly-monthly`, therefore user 2 has switched **once**

User 3 has gone from `monthly-yearly-yearly`, therefore user 3 has switched **once**.

```
> test[order(test$time),] 
   user_id                time    plan
8        2 2017-01-15 19:00:00  yearly
10       1 2017-01-30 19:00:00 monthly
7        1 2017-05-09 20:00:00  yearly
5        2 2017-05-11 20:00:00  yearly
3        3 2017-06-03 20:00:00 monthly
1        1 2017-06-23 20:00:00 monthly
4        1 2017-07-03 20:00:00 monthly
2        2 2017-07-20 20:00:00 monthly
6        3 2017-07-27 20:00:00  yearly
9        3 2017-08-18 20:00:00  yearly
```

My objective is to summarize the combinations of switches, in other words, to summarize how many users have gone from `yearly` to `monthly`, how many have gone from `monthly` to `yearly`, and how many have switched plans multiple times.   The output of the following dataset might look something like this:

```
> output
            type count
1 monthly-yearly     1
2 yearly-monthly     1
3       multiple     1
```

How would one go about grouping by `user_id` and then reducing the sequences of strings in R to either `multiple`, `monthly-yearly`, or `yearly-monthly` ?  Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated.

The dataset above:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(user_id = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1), time = structure(c(1498262400, 
1500595200, 1496534400, 1499126400, 1494547200, 1501200000, 1494374400, 
1484524800, 1503100800, 1485820800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), plan = c("monthly", "monthly", "monthly", "monthly", "yearly", 
"yearly", "yearly", "yearly", "yearly", "monthly")), .Names = c("user_id", 
"time", "plan"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `dplyr` and the useful `rle` function (run-length encoding)..

```
library(dplyr)

output <- test %>% group_by(user_id) %>% #group by id
      arrange(time) %>%                  #sort by date
      summarise(first=first(plan),switches=length(rle(plan)$values)) %>% 
                                         #find first plan and number of switches
      mutate(type=ifelse(switches>2,"multiple",
                     ifelse(first=="monthly","monthly-yearly","yearly-monthly"))) %>% 
                                         #convert these to your three types
      count(type)                        #short for group_by and n()

output
            type     n
           <chr> <int>
1 monthly-yearly     1
2       multiple     1
3 yearly-monthly     1
```

Comment: thanks but what do you mean by "find first plan" ? the first plan in what sense?

Comment: Whether the first one was monthly or yearly for that customer. So that if rle=2 we can tell which way the switch must have been.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way:

```
test[order(user_id, time), 
  .(plan = first(plan))
, by=.(user_id, rleid(user_id, plan))][, 
  if (.N < 3L) paste(plan, collapse="-") 
  else "multiple"
, by=user_id][, 
  .N
, by=.(pattern = V1)]

#           pattern N
# 1:       multiple 1
# 2: yearly-monthly 1
# 3: monthly-yearly 1
```

Translated to dplyr, building on @AndrewGustar's answer:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
    group_by(user_id) %>%
    arrange(time) %>% 
    summarise(pattern = 
      if (length(r <- rle(plan)$values) < 3) paste(r, collapse="-") 
      else "multiple"
    ) %>% 
    count(pattern)

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#          pattern     n
#            <chr> <int>
# 1 monthly-yearly     1
# 2       multiple     1
# 3 yearly-monthly     1
```

*How it works*

To break down how it works, try running it partially, up to each `]` or parenthesis before a `%>%`.

It ...

1. uses `rleid` to group runs of each `plan` value;
2. summarises each user by sequence of runs, writing "multiple" for any sequence of 3+;
3. and counts users by these summaries.

It doesn't use the particular values of `plan`.